# Takesaki II Lemma 1.13: stuck in proof

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, von-neumann-algebras, unbounded-operators

Consider the following fragment from Takesaki's book "Theory of operator algebras II" (Lemma 1.13 on p8, in chapter VI "Left Hilbert algebras"): [image]
[image]

Here, we associate with an operator $\eta \in \mathcal{D}^{b}$ a closed (unbounded) operator $\pi_r(\eta)$ with polar decompositions $\pi_r(\eta) = uh = ku$ as in the following two lemmas:

[image]

[image]

For further notations and conventions, I refer to the previous pages in the book.

Two questions about the proof of this lemma:

1. Why are the marked equalities true? It probably suffices to show the first one, the second one will be similar.
2. Why do we have $f(k)\eta\in \mathfrak{A}'?$ Maybe we have
   $$\pi_r(\mathfrak{A}')\mathcal{D}^b \subseteq \mathcal{D}^b?$$
   This would be sufficient to conclude. Or maybe we even have
   $$\pi_r(\mathcal{D}^b)\mathcal{D}^b \subseteq \mathcal{D}^b?$$
3. Why does there exist a net $\{a_i\}\subseteq \mathfrak{A}$ such that $\pi_l(a_i)\to 1$ strongly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The marked inequalities follow from properties of the polar decomposition of closed densely defined operators. More precisely, if $x=u\lvert x\rvert$ is the polar decomposition of a closed densely defined operator $x$ on $H$ and $g\in C_0([0,\infty))$, we have $g(\lvert x\rvert)=u^\ast g(\lvert x^\ast\rvert)u+(1-u^\ast u)g(0)$. In particular, if $g(0)=0$, then $g(\lvert x\rvert)=u^\ast g(\lvert x^\ast\rvert)u$.

   To see this,  first let $g_\lambda(t)=(t+\lambda)^{-1}$ for $\lambda \notin \mathbb R$. We have
   \begin{align*}
   (u^\ast g_\lambda(|x^\ast|)u+\lambda^{-1}(1-u^\ast u))(|x|+\lambda)&=u^\ast(|x^\ast|+\lambda)^{-1}u(u^\ast|x^\ast|u+\lambda)+1-u^\ast u\\
   &=u^\ast(|x^\ast|+\lambda)^{-1}(|x^\ast|+\lambda)u+1-u^\ast u\\
   &=1.
   \end{align*}
   Here we used that $u^\ast u|x|=|x|$ and $u u^\ast|x^\ast|=|x^\ast|$ by the definition of the polar decomposition.
   Thus $u^\ast g_\lambda(|x^\ast|)u+(1-u^\ast u)g_\lambda(0)=(|x|+\lambda)^{-1}=g_\lambda(|x|)$.
   By Stone-Weierstraß, the functions $t\mapsto (t+\lambda)^{-1}$ with $\lambda\notin \mathbb R$ generate a dense subspace of $C_0([0,\infty))$, and the claim for arbitary $g\in C_0([0,\infty))$ follows by approximation.

2. Write $f= \overline{f_1} f_2$ with $f_1, f_2 \in \mathcal{K}(0, \infty)$. Then
   $$f(k)\eta= f_1(k)^*f_2(k)\eta \in \pi_r(\mathfrak{A}')^*\mathfrak{B}'\subseteq \pi_r(\mathfrak{B'})^*\mathfrak{B}'\subseteq \mathfrak{A}'$$
   by lemma 1.9(1) in the same chapter of Takesaki's book.
3. The algebra $\pi_\ell(\mathfrak A)$ is non-degenerate by definition of a left Hilbert algebra, hence the identity is contained in its strong closure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that $\pi_l(\mathfrak{A})$ is non-degenerate, however how does this imply that the identity is in the strong closure? For $C^*$-algebras, this is an argument using approximate units but we don't have that here.

Comment: You can first pass to the norm closure, which is a $C^\ast$-algebra and contained in the strong closure.

Comment: Thanks, I see now. The norm closure $B$ of $\pi_l(\mathfrak{A})$ is a non-degenerate $C^*$-subalgebra of $B(H)$. Thus, $\operatorname{id}_H$ is in the strong closure of $B$. But the strong closure of $B$ and $\pi_l(\mathfrak{A})$ are the same.

Comment: Seems right. Please go ahead and include it in the answer - that's why I made it community wiki.

Comment: Revisiting this answer, I realise that it is not immediately clear to me why we have $g(|x|)\xi = ug(|x^*|)u^*$ for $g$ continuous with $g(0)=0$ and $\xi \in E([0,R])H$. I guess my main problem is the following: if $|x^*| = \int_0^\infty t dF(t)$ is the spectral decomposition, then we have 
$$\langle u^* g(|x^*|)u \xi, \eta\rangle = \int_0^\infty g dF_{uE([0,R]\xi, u\eta}$$
and we want to make this an integral over $[0,R]$ to ensure that we can apply the uniform convergence. However, for this, we need something like $uE([0,R])= E([0,R])u$ on $E([0,R])H$ but I don't see why this holds

Comment: I would be grateful if you could help me fill in the remaining detail :)

Comment: You're right, that seems indeed unclear (I don't remember if I had an argument in mind for that as it is indeed true, a posteriori). But the new argument I added avoids this problem altogether in using resolvents instead of polynomials for approximation.

Comment: Thanks! How did you think about this technique? And don't you mean $u^*g_\lambda(|x^*|)u$ instead of $u^*g_\lambda(|x^*|+\lambda)u$?

Comment: I also don't understand how you get to the line $u^*u - \lambda^{-1}|x|-u^*u$.

Comment: I added some details. I hope it's a bit clearer now. I also changed to a version with arbitrary value at $0$, I think that makes it a bit more transparent.

Comment: In general, there are not so many common variants to approximate continuous functions of self-adjoint operators, and resolvents are one of them. As the operators are continuous, you could probably also use the generated semigroups. As an exercise, you may try to show that given the spectral measure $E$ of $|x^\ast|$, the assignment $A\mapsto u^\ast E(A)u+\delta_0(A)(1-u^\ast u)$ defines a spectral measure that integrates to $|x|$. That might be the most elegant way to show this.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it!